# How to add base values to different groups in python?

Tags: select, return-value, addition, pyodbc

I have a data set where i have different groups, that seems like this:

```
A           B
Base1      100  
MemberA    Base1+1
MemberB    Base1+2
Base2      250
MemberC    Base2+1
MemberD    Base2+2
etc.
```

I have created new colums with pandas (df), that contains the Group names and the values to be added to base and also one that shows if there is a '+' in the cell (col.B) (position) or not (-1). I also saved it as an excel file that i opened with pyodbc.

```
A           B           c           D     E
Base1      100         Nan         Nan    -1
MemberA    Base1+1     Base1        1     5
MemberB    Base1+2     Base1        2     5
Base2      250         Nan         Nan    -1
MemberC    Base2+1     Base2        1     5
MemberD    Base2+2     Base2        2     5
etc.
```

I want to create another column (F) where the base values are added to the numbers in col. D and then save it as excel file.

```
A           B           c           D        E      F
Base1      100         Nan         Nan       -1    Nan
MemberA    Base1+1     Base1        1         5    101
MemberB    Base1+2     Base1        2         5    102
Base2      250         Nan         Nan       -1    Nan
MemberC    Base2+1     Base2        1         5    251
MemberD    Base2+2     Base2        2         5    252
etc.
```

I tried to solve it with pyodbc like this:

```
crsr.exeute("SELECT C FROM Table WHERE E > 0")
    for row in crsr.fethcall():
        crsr.execute("SELECT B FROM Table WHERE A=?", row)
        while True:
          row=crsr.fetchone()
          if row==None:
            break
          else:
            initial= row
            value = initial + D
```

but it's only gives D values to the last group's base value.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain where you are creating these columns. Are you pulling the information into a pandas DataFrame and manipulating it there? Or are you creating a new table in the database? What are you doing with `value` once you've created it?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile i've found a solution. Not the best, but it's works for me.

```
listA=[]
crsr.exeute("SELECT C FROM Table WHERE E > 0")
    for row in crsr.fethcall():
        crsr.execute("SELECT B FROM Table WHERE A=?", row)
        while True:
          row2=crsr.fetchone()
          if row==None:
            break
          else:
            row2=pd.to_numeric(row2)
            crsr.execute("SELECT D FROM Table WHERE C=?",row)
            while True:
                row3=crsr.fetchone()
                if row3==None:
                   break
                else:
                   listA.extend(row2)
                   row3=pd.to_numeric(row3)
                   value= row3 + row2
                   listA.extend(value)
listA=list(dict.fromkeys(listA))
Table["F"]=listA
```

And I get this result:

```
A           B           c           D        E      F
Base1      100         Nan         Nan       -1    100
MemberA    Base1+1     Base1        1         5    101
MemberB    Base1+2     Base1        2         5    102
Base2      250         Nan         Nan       -1    250
MemberC    Base2+1     Base2        1         5    251
MemberD    Base2+2     Base2        2         5    252
etc.
```